# Jquery : Multiple BigInt and Number

Tags: jquery

I want to multiple BigInt and Number:

```
        let price10 = 10;
        let countLicenses = $(this).find('.field').val(); //it is string
        let resultPrice = countLicenses * price10;
        $(this).find('.result').text(resultPrice);
```

how can I multiple them?

Comment: is `countLicenses` a string that represent a big integer?

Comment: @it-goldman. let countLicenses = "2374923747828497293847493872397423984"

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can use the regular operators for this. The most notable difference is that BigInt number is an object that isn't converted to string automatically when printed. So `toString()` it.

```js
var a = "2374923747828497293847493872397423984"
var b = 10

var big_a = BigInt(a)
var big_b = BigInt(b)

var result = big_a * big_b
console.log(""+result)
// or
console.log(result.toString())
```